# How to Enable MongoDB authentication Programmable

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms, localhost

How can Enable MongoDB authentication Programmable,
I know to enable it you must change in "mongod.cfg" and add

```
security:
authorization: enabled
```

but this file need administration to edit it , so how can edit it in c# code or how to enable authentication by code

Comment: Access control can only be enabled (or disabled) via server configuration, which requires permissions to restart the `mongod` process. You cannot change this server configuration via a client/driver connection. However, your `mongod` process does not have to run as a root/administrative user (and ideally should run as a service user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file requires administrative privileges to edit it, your application will need to be run with administrative privileges in order to edit it. If the file is set to require elevated privileges it would make no sense to allow an unprivileged application to edit the file. As far as I know, there is no way to enable security in the service through code.

I am using that file to enable security also. What I do is edit it during the installation process using InstallShield. This may be the best option for you. Of course, as always, if you have the file permissions set to require elevated privileges, the installer will need to be run as administrator.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the second method is the solution, I must modify the file at the time of installation